# How do I filter a form submit of any select fields where an option with a blank or no value has been selected?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have form markup like...

```
<form id='cart' action="/cart/add" method="post">
    <div id="product-variants">
        <div class="selector-wrapper clearfix">
        <select class="product-select" name='id[]'>
            <option value="">&nbsp;---</option>
            <option value="a">Option A</option>
            <option value="b">Option B</option>
            <option value="c">Option C</option>
        </select>
        <select class="product-select" name='id[]'>
            <option value="">&nbsp;---</option>
            <option value="a">Option A</option>
            <option value="b">Option B</option>
            <option value="c">Option C</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to write a routine that filters out (disables) any select inputs where the value is blank so it doesn't get sent to the backend that I don't have control. Here is what I came up with based on answers to other questions I found here.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#cart").submit(function(){
    $(this).children(':input[value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).children('select option[value=""]').parent().attr("disabled","disabled");
    return true; // ensure form still submits
  });
});
```

The second line of the submit function is not working though. I've tried several combinations and can't figure out how to achieve this. Could anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: logic would disable every select that has an option with `value=""` regardless whether an option with value was selected or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(this).find('select').filter(function() {
      return this.value === ''
 }).prop("disabled", true);
```

OR

```
$(this).find('select').each(function() {
     if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
     }
});
```

**FULL CODE**

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#cart").submit(function(e) {
       // e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('select').each(function() {
            if (this.value == '') {
                $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery("#cart").submit();
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5LBK4/)**

[Another One](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5LBK4/1/)

Comment: need to remove `e.preventDefault();` in production code or form will never submit. Triggering submit by code on page load??

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#cart").submit(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find(':input').prop('disabled',function(){/* ':input will find select and input tags*/
        return $(this).val() =='';
   });
});
```

Returning true is redundant in the submit handler. The other issue with initial code is `select` and `input` elements aren't children of the form. `children` are direct descendents